# Recaptcha for Android iOS hybrid app

Tags: android, ios, recaptcha, hybrid-mobile-app

We are working on a hybrid iOS and android app (we leverage the power of webview to render html files stored locally in android/iOS), where we are looking for some captcha library to integrate with, we found reCaptcha from google exactly on what we need, but, we are not sure if reCaptcha can actually be integrated with a mobile app or we can integrate it only with websites?